Async with condition - Python
I created a python script that brings some data back from various APIs for accountIds list provided to it.
One API is crucial for the result of other APIs, however while using the script I noticed there can be some API calls to that crucial API that can be avoided, hence I thought of using asyncio.Condition()
However, What I'm facing is that my condition seems not be to honoured and still the API is called.
Example:
Providing a list of 3 accounts. Crucial API is called concurrently for them, but I need them to wait for a specific check to happen (if account is present in a dict then get the data from that dict) - that dict starts empty and data flows to it only if it is empty.
I need each task to wait for the previous task to finish and based on its result it whether gets the data from the dict or call the API.
So if first account is a PAYER, then get its children and update the dict.
Now the next task with other accounts (which might be children of that payer) needs to check if their account is in the dict and if not, they can proceed with the API call, otherwise, they need to use the data form the dict.
my code is:
self.initiated_data_dict = {
            "Roles": {},
            "Details": {},
            "Children": {},
            "PayersOfChildren": {}
        }
self.in_progress = {}
self.checker = []


def find_role(self, account_id):
        """Determine the role of the account from the initiated data dictionary."""
        logger.debug(f'Starting find_role for account_id: {account_id}')
        logger.debug(f'Current initiated_data_dict: {json.dumps(self.initiated_data_dict, indent=4)}')

        if account_id in self.initiated_data_dict["Roles"]:
            logger.debug(f'Role found in find_role_ROLES: {account_id}')
            return self.initiated_data_dict["Roles"][account_id]

        if self.initiated_data_dict["Children"]:
            if account_id in self.initiated_data_dict["Children"].keys():
                logger.debug(f'Role found in find_role_CHILDREN_KEYS: {account_id}')
                return "PAYER"
            for children_list in self.initiated_data_dict["Children"].values():
                if any(child.get("accountId") == account_id for child in children_list):
                    logger.debug(f'Role found in find_role_CHILDREN_VALUES: {account_id}')
                    return "LINKED"

        if self.initiated_data_dict["PayersOfChildren"]:
            if account_id in self.initiated_data_dict["PayersOfChildren"]:
                logger.debug(f'Role found in find_role_PayersOfChildren_KEYS: {account_id}')
                return "LINKED"
            
            if account_id in self.initiated_data_dict["PayersOfChildren"].values():
                logger.debug(f'Role found in find_role_PayersOfChildren_VALUES: {account_id}')
                return "PAYER"

        logger.debug(f'Role not found: {account_id}: dict_: {json.dumps(self.initiated_data_dict, indent=4)}')
        return None



async def initiate(self, accountId, condition):
        role_result = None
        children_result = None
        async with condition:
            # Wait until the role for `accountId` is not being processed by another task
            while accountId in self.in_progress:
                await condition.wait()
            if accountId not in self.initiated_data_dict["Roles"] and accountId not in self.in_progress:
                self.checker.append(accountId)
                self.in_progress[accountId] = True
                # Notify other tasks that this task is now in progress
                condition.notify_all()

        # Determine the role of `accountId` using `find_role`
        role_result = self.find_role(accountId)

        if role_result is None:
            # If `accountId` was not found, get the role and update data
            role_result = await model.get_role(accountId)
            logger.debug(f"API Called for {accountId}: Role is: {role_result}")
            self.initiated_data_dict["Roles"][accountId] = role_result
            # logger.debug(f"initiated_data_dict after ROLE API CALL {json.dumps(self.initiated_data_dict, indent=4)}")
            
            if role_result == "PAYER":
                children_result = await model.get_children(accountId)
                self.initiated_data_dict["Children"][accountId] = children_result
                # logger.debug(f"initiated_data_dict after CHILDREN API CALL {json.dumps(self.initiated_data_dict, indent=4)}")
            
        self.initiated_data_dict["Roles"][accountId] = role_result

        async with condition:
            # Safely remove the key from self.in_progress if it exists
            self.in_progress.pop(accountId, None)
            # Notify all tasks that processing is complete
            condition.notify_all()

        return role_result, children_result


async def initiate_data(self, exclude_linked_accounts: bool):
        """
        Initiates data for all accounts.
        This function helps in avoiding duplicate API calls by initiating the data and saving it to self.initiated_data_dict.
        :param exclude_linked_accounts: If True, will exclude linked accounts.
        :return: None
        """
        try:
            self.extended_accountIds = self.original_account_ids_list.copy()
            self.accountData.accountIds_counter = len(self.original_account_ids_list)
            tasks = {}
            condition = asyncio.Condition()
            # async def initiate(accountId):
            #     children_result = None
            #     role_result = await model.get_role(accountId)
            #     if role_result == "PAYER": # Making sure get children is triggered only if role is PAYER
            #         children_result = await model.get_children(accountId)
            #     return role_result, children_result
                
            tasks = {accountId: asyncio.create_task(self.initiate(accountId, condition)) for accountId in self.original_account_ids_list}
            results = await asyncio.gather(*tasks.values())
            for accountId, (role_result, children_result) in zip(tasks.keys(), results):
                # role_result, children_result = await result
                self.initiated_data_dict["Roles"].update({accountId: role_result})

    # rest of my code

I'm not able to figure out what am I doing wrong that is causing the API to be called for all accounts.

I'm not going through all your code. So, please explain why you have been using a Condition instead of a normal if to make an conditional API call.

if I use normal if, it won't stop other tasks from continuing on the condition. all of them will check the if at the same time and won't be waiting on the previous task to inform them. all accounts are fired at the same time in this code block: tasks = {accountId: asyncio.create_task(self.initiate(accountId, condition)) for accountId in self.original_account_ids_list}

Your question contains too much code we wouldn´t need the details about, and some missing code for this to be a minimal reproducible example.  Makes this hard to go through and answer.
In particular, it is hard to perceive what is your intent wth this -
It looks like the calls to the API are just await model.get_role(accountId) and await model.get_children(accountId), correct?
But this code calls both in sequence within the same co-routine, and I can´t see why the sophisticated mechanism to allow other tasks to continue processing the same account ID between calls.
If your problem is the underlying remote API being called in an interleaved way with different account ID's, this approach does nothing to prevent that.
The main problem there, although it is confuse, is that there is no "re-run"  for an initiate task if the role retrieved for it is None: the method just goes on, frees-up the in_progress marker, it doesn't ever run again for the same accountId so that the role result may be different once other accounts had been retrieved.
You´d need a "while" loop, or re-schedule the task if that is your intent - it is really not easy to tell.
